# SwiftUI ContextMenu location

Tags: swiftui, contextmenu

I have a SwiftUI macOS app with a view that contains vertical lines drawn using Path. I need to right-click on a line and open a ContextMenu BUT I need to know the location of the click in order to identify the line that was clicked.

I've tried a normal ContextMenu (it works) but I can't see any way to get it's origin.

```
.contextMenu {
  Button("Do it") { /* do something at button's origin */ }
}
```

I've tried a SpatialTapGesture, it provides a location but I don't know how to make it open a ContextMenu (it also doesn't really do right-click, only ctrl-left click).

```
SpatialTapGesture()
  .modifiers(.control)
  .onEnded { event in
    print("ctrl-click: location = \(event.location)")
  }
```

The code that draws the lines is this:

```
Path { path in
  var xPosition: CGFloat = (-low.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: params.spacing)) * pixelPerHz
  repeat {
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: height))
    xPosition += pixelPerHz * params.spacing
  } while xPosition < width
}
.stroke(color, lineWidth: 1)
.contentShape(Rectangle())

.contextMenu {
  Button("Do it") { /* do something */ }
}
```

I tried changing the line drawing to this:

```
ForEach(Array(legends.enumerated()), id:\.offset) { offset, _ in
  Path { path in
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: (CGFloat(offset) * spacing) * pixelPerHz, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (CGFloat(offset) * spacing) * pixelPerHz, y: height))
  }
  .stroke(color, lineWidth: 1)
  .contentShape(Rectangle())
  .contextMenu {
    Button("Do It") { print("Do It button, line: \(offset + 1)") }
  }
}
```

If you move the .contextMenu up above the .contentShape then you must click exactly on one of the lines (hard since they are 1 wide). When you do, the contextMenu does know which line.

If you leave the .contextMenu where it's shown, you can click anywhere BUT the line number (offset in this code) always is the last line's number.

I need to be able to click anywhere in the x direction. This is a spectrum display and the purpose of the context menu is to tell the app to create something at that frequency. See the picture below.

[image]
Suggestions?

Comment: can't you put an own `.contextMenu` on each line, i.e. have a subview creating one line together with it's own context menu?

Comment: ChrisR -  I edited the post to show the code that draws the lines. Now they are all drawn as part of one Path. I suppose I could draw them individually. I'll make test version that does that and see how it goes. Once I finish that I'll post the result.

Comment: see my edits, I couldn't make the individual line drawing work correctly.

Comment: ok, I see ... then it might be better to go with `.onTapGesture { location in ... }` which gives you the click position and create your own info overlay menu there.

Comment: On macOS can you make a tap gesture respond to a right-click? I don’t think so. I’ve thought of using single and double taps. Other similar apps use right-click for one function and left-click for a different function but I might be able to use single and double click for the equivalent functions.

Comment: unfortunately you are right, so far cotextMenu seems to be the only thing that reacts to right-click. You can go with singe/double click, or click + command / shift / option etc. with `TapGesture().modifiers(...)`

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out.

If you put this in the view:

```
.onAppear(perform: {
  NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.rightMouseDown]) {
    rightMouseDownLocation = $0.locationInWindow
    return $0
  }
})

.contextMenu {
  Button("Do it") { print("Do it: \(self.rightMouseDownLocation.x)") }
}
```

With an:

@State var rightMouseDownLocation: NSPoint = .zero

At the top of the view code. When you right-click you get a contextMenu and the mouse location where the right-click occurred is in the  rightMouseDownLocation var.

Way too complicated but it works.

Answer (score 0):

**updated**
How about this (as a starting point):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<10) { step in
                Line(value: Double(step), color: .gray)
                ForEach(0..<49) { substep in
                    Line(value: Double(step) + Double(substep) / 50, color: .clear)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}


struct Line: View {
    
    let value: Double
    let color: NSColor
    @State private var hover = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Color(hover ? .green : color)
            .frame(width: 2)
            .onHover { hover = $0 }
            .contextMenu {
                Text("Line: \(value)")
                Button("Set freqency") {}
                Button("Clear all") {}
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I think this has the issue that you will only be able to obtain the line number. The x direction represents a continuous range of frequency. You want to be able to click anywhere along the x axis and derive a relative position (which represents a frequency somewhere between the leftmost and the rightmost frequencies). I tried something similar in one of my edits to my post.

Comment: updated my answer approach for that.